# Error in Susskind's "The Theoretical Minimum"?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

Susskind's "The Theoretical Minimum", p. 117:

[image]

Why isn't the last formula
$$ \mathcal{A} = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \biggl[\frac{1}{2}m\Bigl(\dot{X}+\dot{f}\Bigr)^2-V\bigl(X \color{red}{+ f(t)}\bigr)\biggr] \, d t\, .$$

Well, ok, it could be a different potential energy, but then I think it's a bit confusing to still use $V$... should be $V'$ or so...

Comment: The new $V(X)$ gives the same value as the old $V(x)$ where $x = X + f(t)$. There is little more to this than that.

Comment: Hi Amateur, I think you are correct that "George" has implicitly defines a new $V$ in the last line. I agree it's confusing, although in higher level physics it is common to do things like this to avoid cluttering notation when the meaning can be inferred from context.  This point could have been made clearer in the book.